How to let player determine path through a tunnel at runtime?
I'm trying to create a game/animation where the player is traveling in an infinite tunnel and they have control over where the tunnel goes next. Imagine you were in a subway train's driver cab and you could give commands "turn left", "turn right" and that's where the tunnel would then lead you to go.
Note: I understand this might not make sense all the time, for example if there is a long straight section ahead, then suddenly going left doesn't make sense. But it does make sense in some cases: if you are currently turning right, then suddenly going left is  possible.
What I've already tried:
I used curves to create the tunnel and the "Follow path" constraint to make the camera follow the curve. Then if the player wants to turn left, I would add a new control point a little bit ahead of where the player is currently, and twist it so that it's a left turn. The problem with this is that it makes the entire curve longer/shorter, and thus the camera will move as well. (because it's current position is a function of the length)


If this is a question about live interaction  with  player controls, it's a game engine of one sort or another. https://upbge.org/#/ is still supported here, but frankly you will find better answers in their communities.  If it's a question of creating assets (not interactive themselves), then please specify a little further for us?
